# Why does AccessibleChildren not return the same number of elements as specified?

Tags: winapi, accessibility, microsoft-ui-automation

When calling `AccessibleChildren` the call convention is as follows:

```
HRESULT AccessibleChildren(
  IAccessible *paccContainer,
  LONG        iChildStart,
  LONG        cChildren,
  VARIANT     *rgvarChildren,
  LONG        *pcObtained
);
```

Example simplified:

```
AccessibleChildren(ptr, 0, ptr.accChildCount, refArray, refNum)
```

the odd thing is, on several occasions `ptr.accChildCount` does not return the same number as that returned by `refNum`. In all cases `refNum <= ptr.accChildCount`, but why would `AccessibleChildren` not get references all requested children?

Comment: not sure on this (hence comment) but is it because certain items serve no purpose other than for information. So your `refNum` is referring to items that a screen reader directly interacts with and `accChildCount` includes things like containers which may be used to label those items / group them? You could set up a test for that and see if the counts make sense (one container, 4 children items, see if you get counts of 4 and 5 respectively?)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie perhaps, When I tried to get all accessible children of the Desktop window it returned about 20 or so fewer than were present in accChildCount. Maybe it also has something to do with hidden children? Indeed would have to test.

Comment: On calling `AccessibleChildren`, `cChildren` specifies the number of elements you have accommodated for the results. On exit, `*pcObtained` names the number of elements actually written. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessiblechildren) *explicitly* calls out, that *"if you request more children than exist, this value will be less"*. Why do you expect those values to be the same? In other words: Why do you think that `*pcObtained` were to be superfluous?

Comment: [The number of children in an object can change.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-iaccessible-get_accchildcount#remarks) Could you check if you receive `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` event generated by the object in the case `refNum < ptr.accChildCount`?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT That's a good point and something I should check for sure! What is odd though is `obj.accChildCount` is from my testing constant, where as if it were changing I'd expect `obj.accChildCount` to fluctuate. However I will attempt to hook onto `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` next time I test.

Comment: @IInspectable my major confusion was that `obj.accChildCount` is not equal to the number returned from `AccessibleChildren`. Both numbers (the number returned by `AccessibleChildren` and the number returned by `accChildCount` are consistent across successive calls... I mainly wondered whether there were a real reason e.g. windows the desktop knows about but won't provide access to due to user permissions etc.

Comment: @Sancarn Is "object destroy" your case? I can reproduce this issue when [`paccContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessiblechildren) is desktop window but other application windows like Chrome give me the equal number from `refNum` and `ptr.accChildCount`.